# Google Cloud Messaging (fake_message_id)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I have node.js server:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');

// create a message with default values
var message = new gcm.Message();

// or with object values
var message = new gcm.Message({
    collapseKey: 'demo',
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
    data: {
        key1: 'message1',
        key2: 'message2'
    }
});

var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyChp2jTQsgPkLaaVgFh6yoovu1Td7tuQMo');
var registrationIds = [];

// OPTIONAL
// add new key-value in data object
message.addDataWithKeyValue('key1','message1');
message.addDataWithKeyValue('key2','message2');

// or add a data object
message.addDataWithObject({
    key1: 'message1',
    key2: 'message2'
});

// or with backwards compability of previous versions
message.addData('key1','message1');
message.addData('key2','message2');


message.collapseKey = 'demo';
message.delayWhileIdle = true;
message.timeToLive = 3;
message.dryRun = true;
// END OPTIONAL

// At least one required
registrationIds.push('APA91bGV0W6lgapC07aHc-sQdd462f_lCoUY0r5mqVtdFX1ZfK31njMUeyVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0SiAp29dkyxdJ5Y8Cl2tO1aih0KeViA9hK3Q47atoU8qsD6ITbg');


/**
 * Params: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
 **/
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I got an:

> { multicast_id: -1, 
>   success: 1,  failure: 0,  canonical_ids: 0,  results:
>   [ { message_id: fake_message_id' } ] }

And message does not send to receivers.

What does fake_message_id mean?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looking at your code, I can see that you set the property dryRun of the message to true:

```
message.dryRun = true;
```

By doing this you are telling the Google servers that this is a testing message to see if all keys are properly configured. 
If you comment out that line, or set the property to false (its default value) then the message will be handled as a real message.

DryRun answers are also easily spotted by their multicast_id, which will always be -1

Answer (score 0):

For token that is invalid, it will show message like below:

```
{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Or

```
{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

With this in the response:

```
"success":0,"failure":1
```